looping through classes using require
I have a number of plugin classes each of which have a method 'enable'.
The following code works
unit class Top;
has $!rdp;
use Plugin::A;
use Plugin::B;
use Plugin::C;
submethod TWEAK {
  my $rdp := self.rdp;
  Plugin::A.new.enable($rdp);
  Plugin::B.new.enable($rdp);
  Plugin::C.new.enable($rdp);
}

The Plugin... classes are only used once to prepare $rdp, so I thought it would not matter whether the classes are looked up at run time or compile time.
I would like something of the form
for <A B C> {
  require ::("Plugin::$_");
  ::("Plugin::$_").new.enable($rdp)
}

I tried a variety of syntaxes, none of which work.
What would be a way to do this?

A perfect Q will "Describe what you’ve already tried and the results of any research". Did you do more than try "a variety of syntaxes"? You didn't mention try, but did you try that? You didn't mention searching (google, SO, Rakudo issues), but did you try that too? I did a search of Rakudo issues for "try require packages"; did you try something like that? Please consider adding such details to your Q. TIA!

@raiph all reasonable criticisms. I try to give a minimal question. Yes, lots of searching.

TL;DR I've guessed at what you mean. I may be miles off, so this answer may be useless. Even if I guessed correctly, the answer may still be useless or hide problems that will surface in months/years to come because there are related open package loading issues that have not been fully debugged so any solution is just a workaround that happens to work in a given Rakudo release but may not work in the next.

My guess is that you're looking for something like this, which works in the Rakudo (from 2022) that's installed on glot.io at the time of writing this (2024):
for <A B C> {
  my $OK = True;
  require ::("Plugin::$_");
  CATCH { $OK = False; .resume }
  ::("Plugin::$_").new.enable($rdp) if $OK
}


I say "at a guess" because there are many ways to interpret what you wrote and you didn't provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example to help reduce the ambiguity.

My first key discovery as I researched your question was that using the try prefix on require seems to break Rakudo's anticipatory compile time work related to the package symbol corresponding to the package being required. So even if a package was found I couldn't then make use of the package symbol.

My second key discovery was there seem to be many related open issues in the Rakudo issue queue. For example: 1, 2, 3.

You guessed right about Q. I thought I had got the syntax wrong because I could not get code to run. Turns out it may be a RakuAst problem, or something elsewhere. I should have included the error message: Cannot look up attributes in a RakuAST::Package type object. Did you forget a '.new'? Thank you for confirming I had the syntax correct, and that something like this works without the use experimental pragma

update: require in a loop is now working with use experimental :rakuast

Hi @RichardHainsworth Thx. Afaik I don't currently have access to a latest Rakudo that'll let me test code to figure out what you mean but am curious whether you're saying your original code (in your question) currently works on the latest Rakudo if use experimental :rakuast is in effect, or just the code in my answer, or both. Also, I'm wondering if a simple try require ::("Plugin::$_"); (which did not work when I tried it) now works? (I'm guessing it still doesn't.) Also, do you mean that, if a plug-in does not exist, there's no warning or error messages by default?
